# .NET Core 5 middleware InvokeAsync not triggered

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, .net-5

I had a backend solution using a middleware with .NET Core 2.2 and I updated this to .NET Core 5, but the `InvokeAsync` method is no longer triggered.

This is my code:

Startup (in configureservices):

```
app.UseMiddleware<ValidRouteMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ValidNuisAlgoTokenAndAdminMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ValidationCatcherMiddleware>();
```

ValidRouteMiddleware:

```
public class ValidRouteMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<ValidRouteMiddleware> _logger;
    private const string BadRouteErrorMessage = "Hello World d~.~b";
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly List<string> _allRoutes;

    public ValidRouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ValidRouteMiddleware> logger,
       IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        ....
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!MiddlewareTools.CheckRoute(context,_allRoutes))
        {
            _...
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware:

```
    public class CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware> _logger;
        private const string UnauthorizedErrorMessage = "Non autorisé";
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly List<string> _excludedRoutes;

        public CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware> logger,
            IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
        {
            _next = next;
            ...
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ComInDbContext dbContext)
        {
        }
    }
```

etc...

What is missing ?

Regards

Note: The entire Startup/ConfigureServices

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    Logger = logger;
    Logger.LogInformation($"Environnement d'exécution : {Environment.EnvironmentName}");

    appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnApplicationStarted);
    appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnApplicationStopping);
    appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnApplicationStopped);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // Pour la génération des PDFs, on doit injecter la lib en 32 ou 64
    var wkHtmlToPdfContext = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
    var architectureFolder = (IntPtr.Size == 8) ? "64 bits" : "32 bits";
    // Folder dans Infrastructure.PDF
    var wkHtmlToPdfPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"libwkhtmltox\\{architectureFolder}\\libwkhtmltox");
    wkHtmlToPdfContext.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(wkHtmlToPdfPath);

    app.UseRouting();

    // Utilisation de la règle du CORS
    Logger.LogInformation($"Application de la règle `{filteredOrigin}` pour le CORS");
    app.UseCors(filteredOrigin);

    // Swagger uniquement en DEV
    if (Environment.EnvironmentName == "Development" || Environment.EnvironmentName == "PreProduction")
    {
        // Active Swagger
        Logger.LogInformation($"Activation de Swagger (sur l'URL \"/swagger\") ...");
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger - Administration API");
            c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
        });
    }

    // Active les signaux de HealthCheck sur l'url de routage "/health"
    Logger.LogInformation($"Activation des HealthCheck (sur l'URL \"/health\") ...");
    // Active le pipeline d'Endpoints
    Logger.LogInformation($"Activation du pipeline d'Endpoints ...");
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health",
            new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
                {
                    var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                        new
                        {
                            status = report.Status.ToString(),
                            errors = report.Entries.Select(e => new { key = e.Key, value = Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), e.Value.Status) })
                        });
                    context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(result, context.RequestAborted);
                }
            });
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    #region Middleware

    // Active le middleware pour la vérification des headers
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidRouteMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidNuisAlgoTokenAndAdminMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidationCatcherMiddleware>();

    #endregion Middleware
}
```

Comment: Hi@david , Your custom middleware looks fine, can you provide your whole `Configure` in `startup` ?

Comment: Hello, yes, i add the entire méthod in first post

Comment: `I updated this to .NET Core 5` why not .NET 6? .NET 5 is a short term release that reaches End Of Life in 3 months (May 2022). .NET 6 is the actual Long Term Support version. Migrating to .NET 5 is a wasted effort, you'll have to migrate to .NET 6 immediately. Although that may only need a change to `net6.0` from `net5.0` and a package upgrade

Comment: Did this code ever work in .NET Core 2? Middleware order matters, and your middleware is registered after all other middleware. The requests will be handled by the endpoints which won't forward the call to your middleware. Endpoints are supposed to be the last middleware in the chain. HTTPS redirection won't work for the same reason

Comment: yes , agree with@
Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: I suggest you create a new web app project and inspect the generated code, noticing where each middleware is called. Custom middleware should be added *before* any other steps that need it and definitely before the MVC or endpoint middleware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write a simple demo here. First I create a custom middleware and register it before `endpoint` in `Configure` method in `startup`, then you can see InvokeAsync triggered successfully

[image]

When I register middleware after `endpoint`, InvokeAsync will not be triggered .

[image]

Panagiotis Kanavos has explained the `Endpoint` or you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-endpoint-metadata) about routing in Asp .net core 5

Comment: Post code, instead of images or worse, flickering animations that can't be read before they finish. Browsers can't pause animated gifs. Someone would need image processing software to inspect the frames and understand what you posted. Images can't be copied or compiled either

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this code ever worked in .NET Core 2. Middleware blocks process requests in the order they're registered. Everything in ASP.NET Core is a middleware block, including HTTPS, authentication, CORS, controller support, routing, endpoints, with endpoints acting as the *last* step in the middleware chain.

Anything registered after the endpoints will never be called. That includes both the custom middleware *and* the HTTPS redirection step.

The [ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) page in the docs explains how middleware works and the correct [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order)

[image]

At the very least you need to place `UseHttpsRedirection` after the `if (env.IsDevelopment())` block, and register your custom middleware before `UseEndpoints`.

I suggest creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC application and inspecting the code. The middleware is already in the correct order.

**.NET Core LTS versions**

You should also consider skipping .NET 5 and going straight to .NET 6. .NET 5 is a short term release which reaches [End-Of-Life in May 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle). The Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, which will be supported until November 2024.

Migrating to .NET 6 from .NET 5 may be as easy as changing the target to `net5.0` from `net6.0` and upgrading NuGet packages. On the other hand, starting with the new minimal MVC template can reduce the startup code significantly, reducing the chances of errors like this one.

Again, try creating a new empty MVC web app and inspect the generated code.

The [middleware doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) shows a .NET 6 example, where all the Program and Startup.cs code is merged into Program.cs. In the question's case, the custom middleware would be added before the controller and Razor page middleware.

```
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
// app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseRouting();
// app.UseRequestLocalization();
// app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// app.UseSession();
// app.UseResponseCompression();
// app.UseResponseCaching();

    app.UseMiddleware<ValidRouteMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidNuisAlgoTokenAndAdminMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<CheckIdChantierDefaultMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidationCatcherMiddleware>();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

[Write Custom ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0) explains how to write middleware and call middleware.

Comment: The answer actually heralds importance of the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Panagiotis put me on the solution,
i have to call middleware before endPoints, and the invoke are triggered.

Thank you all